# How to achieve this window style in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

This is a screen shot from GIMP: [image: window headers]

There's a regular window header on the left and a smaller, more compact window type on the right. It's something I see from time to time in programs. How can I create such a window in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the property of your `Form` object `FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;`

(also `SizableToolWindow` if you want the user to be able to resize the form).

Answer (score 4):

Look at the properties of Form in properties window, There is property named Style or Sth like that is a dropdown that you can choose between normal windows, dialog and ...

**UPDATE:**
FormBorderStyle  and it's values

- None     No border.
- FixedSingle  A fixed, single-line border.
- Fixed3D  A fixed, three-dimensional border.
- FixedDialog  A thick, fixed dialog-style border.
- Sizable  A resizable border.
- FixedToolWindow  A tool window border that is not resizable. A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the window that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB. Although forms that specify FixedToolWindow typically are not shown in the taskbar, you must also ensure that the ShowInTaskbar property is set to false, since its default value is true.
- SizableToolWindow    A resizable tool window border. A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the window that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at this page for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx